# GWT: Export a CellTable to an image or pdf file

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

I have a CellTable showing data that is plotted in a GFlot SimplePlot.

An export of the plot is possible with GFlots integrated function:

```
    exportImage = plot.getImage();
```

Now I would like to export the CellTable too, to show the corresponding data to the plot.
Is this possible in some way with GWT on the client-side? It needn't to be the CellTable itself, just the data it shows would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use flash4j library:

```
package com.emitrom.flash4j.demo.client;

import com.emitrom.flash4j.clientio.client.ClientIO;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class ClientIOExample implements EntryPoint {
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // initialize the ClientIO module
    ClientIO.init();

    Button b = new Button("Click Me");
    b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // create a PDF File
            PDF pdf = new PDF();
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.setTextStyle(new RGBColor(0x000000));
            pdf.setFont(new CoreFont(), 10);
            pdf.addText("");
            ClientIO.saveFile(pdf.save(), "file.pdf");
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(b);
}
}
```

You can see more detailed information [a link](http://emitrom.com/announcements/flash4j-3.1-ga/)